# Wsus and powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to know if it is possible to move computers in a group from a csv or txt list ...

the script below machine by machine
`Get-WsusServer -Name "contoso" | Get-WsusComputer -NameIncludes "winvm" | Add-WsusComputer -TargetGroupName "Windows Virtual Machines"`
thx a lot

Get-WsusServer -Name "contoso" | Get-WsusComputer -NameIncludes (Get-Content D:\pc.txt) | Add-WsusComputer -TargetGroupName "Windows Virtual Machines"

But it does not work

Answer (score 1):

When I scripted out computer assignments I too put VMs in a different computer group than physical hosts. I did a bit more than that parsing machine names to determine location since we put regional identifiers in our computer naming schema, but just going off if something is a VM you could do this:

```
Import-Module UpdateServices
$WSUS = Get-WsusServer
$AllGroups = $WSUS.GetComputerTargetGroups()
$VMGroup = $AllGroups.Where({$_.Name -eq 'Windows Virtual Machines'})
$AllComputers = $Groups.Where({$_.Name -eq 'All Computers'}).GetComputerTargets()
$ComputerList = Get-Content D:\pc.txt
$AllComputers.Where({$_.Model -eq 'Virtual Machine'})|ForEach-Object{
    $VMGroup.AddComputerTarget($_)
}
```

Or if you want to go off a list of computers in a file:

```
$AllComputers.Where({$_.Name -in $ComputerList})|ForEach-Object{
    $VMGroup.AddComputerTarget($_)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much TheMadTechnician

in fact, the machines are classified by group, for example:
group A= win10 and group B= W11-21-H2
Group C=Win11 22-H2, the goal is to master a certain number of machines in Group C from the list at once